Virtual Disk read only WinServ22
Had to reinstall a Windows Server 2022 VM hosted on Proxmox 8.1.4. I have four 12TB drives passed through to the VM and they were all made into one virtual drive on the previous WinServ22 system. I have it added to the new system and unable to get it out of read only. I have used dskpart to bring the disk online and clear the read only attributes and the attribute say no read only.CHKDSK still says the disk is read only? Even when I manually put the disk online, it converts back to offline and never comes out of read only. Tools I have used...DiskPart, IM-Majic Partition Resizer. What am I doing wrong?
